# How to use @autowired in different classes that implement the same interface with only annotations

Tags: java, spring, oop, spring-mvc

As I can choose which class to call only with annotations? For example i need to call my class "Test_2"

**Interface:**

```
public interface Inter {

 public void useInterface();

}
```

**Class 1:**

```
public class Test_1 implements Inter {

 public void useInterface(){
   System.out.println("Instance Class Test_1");
 }  
}
```

**Class 2:**

```
public class Test_2 implements Inter {

 public void useInterface(){
   System.out.println("Instance Class Test_2");
 }  
}
```

**Class Call:**

```
public class Call {

 @Autowired
 private Inter inter;

 public Call(){
   inter.useInterface();
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you show how you configured your ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

anotate your classes this way:

```
@Component("test1")
public class Test_1 implements Inter {

    public void useInterface(){
        System.out.println("Instance Class Test_1");
    }  
}
```

and use

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("test1")
private Inter inter;
```

Comment: Unless some fancy name is needed, Spring will automatically use the class name in lowercases.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use qualifier, i.e.:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("test_2")
private Inter inter;
```